# UDFRowSequence not working

Tags: java, hadoop, mapreduce, hive, user-defined-functions

I am trying to use auto increment UDF (http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/hive/trunk/contrib/src/java/org/apache/hadoop/hive/contrib/udf/UDFRowSequence.java)

I am getting error when i used this UDF.

Error :

On Hive Console -

```
Exception in Thread 60 - Java nullpointer exception

On Hadoop Web Ui - Error in configuring Object .....caused by java,reflect.Invocation..
```

Does anyone used this UDF?
I am wondering if this UDF runs in Map Phase then how it will be able to give unique numbers to each row?

Answer (score 0):

It worked fine for  me . How are you executing it ?

AS I can see it launches a single mapper process, that why it can give unique numbers to each row.

Comment: But i am not getting unique numbers to each row.After certain value , values are repeating. How you are setting one mapper? For me it launched multiple mappers , say around 100.